# What will happen if I changed the collation of my database?

Tags: mysql, character-encoding, collation

I am trying to increase performance in MySQL. once of the thing that I learned in using Latin1 charset is faster than using UTF8 because latin1 uses less bytes.. But I am wondering what will happen to the data if I changed the collation? in my application today most of the things are in Amerian english but I can't guarantee that there won't be any other languages stores as well. it someone store data other than english I don't really care about that data much.

My question:
1) if I changed the collation in my databases to latin1 what will happen to the data if it was not written in American English?
2) which lation1_? do I use latin1_bin, latin1_general_ci, or latin1_general_cs? and if possible what is the difference?
3) when changing the collation of the database do I need to also change the collation of each table separately?

Thanks

Comment: Is "" not something people might conceivably use in your application? Don't switch to the legacy Latin1 encoding. I'd challenge you to produce a benchmark that shows it's measurably faster or more space efficient. MySQL *reserves* three bytes per UTF-8 character, but it doesn't necessarily use that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UTF 8 only uses extra bytes if it has strange characters.  So really, you should NOT change your collation. it won't help.  UTF 16 was developed to hold all characters of all languages, and yes, it uses 16 bits so if you were using utf16 I would suggest utf8 if you mostly had standard latin characters.  utf 8 is the compromise.  it has a special character that means "more bytes coming", and if it sees it, it groups the next ones together.  But if all you have is latin characters, the bytes will be exactly the same number as with latin collation.

to answer specifically, you can set the default colation for new tables, but yes, you have to do it for each one of the existing ones.  you could do it with an sql statement that lists the tables then runs the sql statement on each, to change it. (change 1 and notice the sql statement).  but again, don't do it. utf8 is the standard for a reason. your performance issues are elsewhere.

Comment: Thank you for the information. However, I attended the MySQL Connect and they did suggest to use latin1 for a faster performance I am so confused now. they said if you can change utf8 to latin1 go for it.

Comment: again, if you truly will only ever have latin characters, just change the collation and "go for it".  it could theoretically be a couple microseconds faster on text based queries since mysql wouldn't have to check for the "more characters coming", but most internal text engines actually convert the text to utf16 when processing anyways. Some "old pro" at MySQL Connect must think Latin one is "simpler" than new fangled utf8 fields, but the current "simple" is the universal utf8 field.  It's your call but I assure you you won't see performance gains "These are not the bytes you're looking for"

Comment: I see. let me ask another thing. If I keep everything at utf8 except external ids? external ids are set as CHAR(18) and they are alphabets and numeric values if I change those to lation1_generic_ci will that make the look up faster? I also have those id columns indexed.

Comment: comparing 2 strings is just as fast in utf8 as latin.  you need to do some tests and set a goal, and figure out what's keeping you from that speed.  if you are likely to have several connections to the db at once, be sure you use innodb tables, not myisaam

Comment: I am using Innodb and not MyIsaam also I am using MySQL 5.6. I will do some speed testing. Thanks :)